# React - How to pass returned data from an exported function to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

How can I pass data I receive from a get request pass over to a component? Whatever I tried wouldn't work but my thinking was as the code below shows..
Thanks!

```
    export function data() {
        axios.get('www.example.de')
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.data
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                this.setState({
                    list: data
                })
            })
    }

    import {data} from './api.js';

    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                list: ""
            };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            data();
        }
        render() {
            return <p > this.state.list < /p>
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log("data.." + data())` inside componentWillMount.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call `this.setState` inside of `data()->then` callback, so `this` is context of the `then` callback function. Instead you should use arrow functions (it does not have its own context) and pass component's `this` to `data` function using `call`

```
export function data() {
    axios.get('www.example.de')
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                list: data
            })
        })
}

import {data} from './api.js';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: ""
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        data.call(this);
    }
    render() {
        return <p > this.state.list < /p>
    }
}
```

However, your data services must not know about `setState` and, event more, expect passing `this` from react component. Your data service must be responsible for retrieving data from server, but not for changing component state, see [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Also, your data service can be called from another data service. So your data service should return promise instead, that can be used by component for calling `setState`.

```
   export function data() {
       return axios.get('www.example.de')
           .then(res => res.data)
   }
```

and then

```
componentWillMount() {
    data().then(data=>{
        this.setState({
            list: data
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! so am I correct to say:  this in the data() context, this is referring to 'data' so im my case data equals an array of objects ().What exactly is this referring here to?

Comment: @javascripting no, this always refers to context https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: your code with call worked great, but if I use your edited code Im getting an error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @javascripting it seems like you missed return statement `return axios.get('www.example.de')`

Comment: thanks, yes i forgot the return. I wonder why do I have to return the axis.get() - and not the res.data ? when I return res.data then I would think that enough (but that would not work)

Answer (score 3):

your `api` shouldn't know anything about your component, you can easily do this with `callback`, like so -

```
export function data(callback) {
    axios.get('www.example.de')
        .then(res => callback({ data: res.data }))
        .catch(err => callback({ error: err }));
}
```

By doing this you can easily unit test your `api`

So in your `Test` component, you simply do -

```
componentWillMount() {
  data(result => {
    const { data, error } = result;
    if (error) {
      // Handle error
      return;
    }

    if (data) {
      this.setState({ list: data });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why its not good to setState insight the exported function?

Comment: your api should only care about getting data from server, this way it's easy to unit test and is reusable because it's not dependant on consumer to call with `this` context

Comment: what is the callback referring to?

Comment: `callback` is just a parameter name for function that you can pass, in this case it's represented by arrow function. you can call whatever makes sense for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 1):

Your request is a promise so you can simply return that from the imported function and use the eventual returned result of that within the component. You only want to be changing the state of the component from within the component.

```
export function getData(endpoint) {
  return axios.get(endpoint);
}
```

Note I've changed the name of the function to something more "actiony".

```
import { getData } from './api.js';

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Your state is going to be an array of things, so
    // initialise it with an array to spare confusion
    this.state = { list: [] };
  }

  // I use ComponentDidMount for fetch requests
  // https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/
  componentDidMount() {

    // We've returned a promise from `getData` so we can still use the
    // promise API to extract the JSON, and store the parsed object as the
    // component state
    getData('www.example.de')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(list => this.setState({ list }))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your external function doesn't have the correct context of `this`, so you'll need to call it with the correct context from within the component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    data.call(this);
}
```

However, inside the API call, it still won't have the correct `this` context, so you can set a variable to point to this inside the data() function:

```
export function data() {
  let that = this;
  axios('http://www.url.com')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      that.setState({
        list: data
      })
    })
}
```

[Details of the this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

However, it's generally considered better practice to only handle your state manipulation from with the component itself, but this will involve handling the asynchronous nature of the GET request, perhaps by passing in a callback to the `data()` function.

EDIT: Updated with asynchronous code

```
//api.js
data(callback){
  axios.get('www.url.com')
    .then(res => callback(res));
}

//component.jsx
componentWillMount(){
  data(res => this.setState({list: res}));
}
```